# How to set a cookie before the goto?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm doing this, in Watir 6.16.5 and Selenium 3.142.3:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new(driver)
b.cookies.add('foo', 'Hello, world!', domain: 'www.example.com')
b.goto('http://www.example.com')
```

I want to set the cookie and *then* go to the website *with* the cookie setting. However, I'm getting:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidCookieDomainError: Document is cookie-averse
            WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:179:5
            InvalidCookieDomainError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:317:5
            GeckoDriver.prototype.addCookie@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:2641:11
```

What am I doing wrong? [This](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6775) may be relevant, but what is the workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be in the same domain to set the cookie. From the [W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#add-cookie)

> If the current browsing context’s document element is a cookie-averse
>   Document object, return error with error code invalid cookie domain.

It's also explained in [invalid cookie domain](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#dfn-invalid-cookie-domain)

> An illegal attempt was made to set a cookie under a different domain
>   than the current page.

A workaround will be to simply refresh the page after setting the cookie in the domain

```
b = Watir::Browser.new(driver)
b.goto('http://www.example.com')
b.cookies.add('foo', 'Hello, world!', domain: 'www.example.com')
b.refresh
```

Comment: What do the foo and hello word here signify? Could you clarify this answer please, I am having trouble getting cookies to work and this is basically all that comes up on SO

Comment: @AliOve those are the name and the value of the cookie being set.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i can give the solution in python how to handle cookies,Hope it may help you in someway.

Once you got the cookies you can store it as:

```
    with open("cookies.pkl","wb") as cookies:
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(),cookies)
```

Note: Need to import pickle for storing the file as pickle file

Retrieving Cookies:

```
def handle_cookies():
    with open("cookies.pkl","rb")as cookies:
        cookie = pickle.load(cookies)
        for ck in cookie:
            driver.add_cookie(ck)
```

On calling this function it handles cookies